# How to nest MimeBodyParts in JavaMail (standard email messages)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email, jakarta-mail, html-email

I'm trying to send an html email (with a text alternative) that includes an embedded/inline image using JavaMail.

I wanted to see what a properly formatted message looked like so I sent one using gmail with an inline image and below is the original source. It seems as if they are nesting body parts in the message. How can I replicate this EXACTLY using javamail. I found no way to put a Multipart inside of another Multipart.

> MIME-Version: 1.0 Received: by 10.50.75.3 with HTTP; Thu, 23 Feb 2012
>   20:15:34 -0800 (PST) Date: Thu, 23 Feb 2012 20:15:34 -0800
>   Delivered-To: x@gmail.com Message-ID:
>   
>   Subject: c From: Foo Bar  To: Foo
>   Bar  Content-Type: multipart/related;
>   boundary=e89a8f3b9b051e124104b9ae03fb
>
> --e89a8f3b9b051e124104b9ae03fb Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=e89a8f3b9b051e123604b9ae03fa
>
> --e89a8f3b9b051e123604b9ae03fa Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
>
> plain text content goes here
>
> --e89a8f3b9b051e123604b9ae03fa Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
>
> --e89a8f3b9b051e123604b9ae03fa--
>   --e89a8f3b9b051e124104b9ae03fb Content-Type: image/png; name="logo.png" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-ID:
>    X-Attachment-Id: ii_135ad92205fc1ace
>
> iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoCAYAAACM/rhtAAAAh0lEQVR42u3ZsQnAIBBGYVtHShVI
>   7ViprASXcw8HMCckEGyTkB98xWsE4WvOwnMhBG/tVrGaSOU0+Q5MVhMtdWAVBlY3HCyW+7nlbhqB
>   TiGAAAECBAhwMqB0AN8ANuUkgQzJvEPy1WP75C5AgAABAgQ4GXATAK4DUP8LOAsD87WGiIJriGj5
>   AwiiiyDxmymtAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
>   --e89a8f3b9b051e124104b9ae03fb--

UPDATE:

Using the standard multipart inline image methods (like those linked to by lechlukasz) produces the following email, not quite what I need:

> MIME-Version: 1.0 Received: by 10.236.146.106 with SMTP id
>   q70mr1894063yhj.0.1330071158663; Fri,  24 Feb 2012 00:12:38 -0800
>   (PST) Reply-To: Foo Bar  Message-ID:
>   <20cf303bfc80f02cfa04b9b152db@google.com> Date: Fri, 24 Feb 2012
>   08:12:38 +0000 Subject: please oh please4 From: Foo Bar
>    To: Foo Bar  Content-Type:
>   multipart/alternative; boundary=20cf303bfc80f02ce704b9b152d6
>
> --20cf303bfc80f02ce704b9b152d6 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed; delsp=yes Content-Transfer-Encoding:
>   base64
>
> 77+9UE5HDQoaDQoAAAANCklIRFIAAAAoAAAAKAgGAAAA77+977+977+9bQAAAO+/vUlEQVR477+9
>   77+977+977+9Ce+/vSAgDQoQRmFbR0oVSO+/vVjvv73vv70E77+9cw8HMCckEGzvv73vv70ffO+/ vWsE77+9a++/ve+/vXMhBG/vv71W77+977+9SO+/vTTvv70OTFYTLXVgFQZWNxws77+977+977+9 77+9bhrvv71OIe+/vQABAgQIcDLvv710AO+/vQA277+9JO+/vQzvv73vv71D77+977+9Y++/ve+/
>   vS5A77+9AAECBDgZcBMA77+9A1Dvv70LOAsD77+977+977+977+977+9a++/vWjvv70DCO+/ve+/ vSDvv73vv70p77+9AAAAAElFTkTvv71CYO+/vQ0K
>   --20cf303bfc80f02ce704b9b152d6 Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
>
> --20cf303bfc80f02ce704b9b152d6--

Answer (score 8):

You put a Multipart in another Multipart by creating a MimeBodyPart, setting the content of that to the Multipart, and adding that body part to the first Multipart.

Answer (score 1):

in essence, this is what to do:

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage( session );
msg.setFrom( "from foo" );
msg.setRecipients( Message.RecipientType.TO, "bar@bus.com" );
msg.setSubject( "subj" );

MimeMultipart altAndAtt = new MimeMultipart( "mixed" );

{ // add alternative plain + html part

    MimeMultipart plainAndHtml = new MimeMultipart( "alternative" );

    MimeBodyPart plain = new MimeBodyPart();
    plain.setContent( plainBody, "text/plain; charset=utf-8" );
    plainAndHtml.addBodyPart( plain );

    MimeBodyPart html = new MimeBodyPart();
    html.setContent( htmlBody, "text/html; charset=utf-8" );
    plainAndHtml.addBodyPart( html );

    MimeBodyPart wrapper = new MimeBodyPart();  // needed for nesting multipart in multipart
    wrapper.setContent( plainAndHtml );
    altAndAtt.addBodyPart( wrapper );
}

{ // add attachment part

    MimeBodyPart attPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    attPart.attachFile( myFilePath );

    altAndAtt.addBodyPart( attPart );
}


msg.setContent( altAndAtt );
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like that:

http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html#IncludingImagesWithHTML

Note that you need also modify your html to specify cid:identifier as image src.

Comment: Nope. That doesn't have a text alternate to the html. Also, it doesn't use nested body parts, just multiple.

Comment: I know I've done something like that, and I've found similar tutorial to that, but I don't have neither link nor code now. The cid's were the most difficult part for me.