# Java Mail - Attachments not showing in email clients?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

Ok so I'm having to alter some old code from another dev that he sent up for sending emails from our app with Java Mail. This has worked fine for a long time but now we are required to send pdf attachments as well.

So basically below, assume there is an object "mail" that has getters for the text and html messages as well as now a getter for the pdf filename to load from the filesystem and attach to the mail.

I've altered the below code where marked, so if there is a pdf to attach, load from filesystem and attach. I've tried to use the same structure as the previous code, although I suspect its not all required?

```
            Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

            // Create a "text" Multipart message
            BodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            textPart.setContent(mail.getText(), "text/plain");
            mp.addBodyPart(textPart);

            // Create a "HTML" Multipart message
            Multipart htmlContent = new MimeMultipart("related");
            BodyPart htmlPage = new MimeBodyPart();

            htmlPage.setContent(mail.getHtml(), "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
            htmlContent.addBodyPart(htmlPage);
            BodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            htmlPart.setContent(htmlContent);
            mp.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

            // NEW CODE STARTS HERE
            if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(mail.getPdfAttachmentFileName())) {
                Multipart pdfContent = new MimeMultipart("mixed"); //<---- this appears to be an issue???
                BodyPart pdfPage = new MimeBodyPart();

                File file = new File(uploadDir + "/" + mail.getPdfAttachmentFileName());
                DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(new FileInputStream(file), "application/pdf");

                pdfPage.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource));
                pdfPage.setFileName(mail.getPdfAttachmentFileName());
                pdfContent.addBodyPart(pdfPage);


                BodyPart pdfPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                pdfPart.setContent(pdfContent);
                mp.addBodyPart(pdfPart);
            }
            // NEW CODE ENDS HERE

            mimeMessage.setContent(mp);
```

At any rate, the above works, sort of. There are no errors or exceptions and the message gets sent. BUT the attachment doesn't appear depending on which email client you recieve the mail with.

With the code as above, Outlook receives the message as readable and the attachment is visible and downloadable. This is perfect. BUT in GMail, the message is still readable, the paperclip appears to indicate there is an attachment, but there is no attachment to download?

If you switch the `Multipart pdfContent = new MimeMultipart("mixed");' to be "related" rather than "mixed" the exact opposite is true. GMail receives it perfectly but Outlook only gets the message and paperclip, no actual attachment.

Obviously we need to be sending emails to our customers with no knowledge of their email client used to open them! Obviously I'm a novice at Java Mail so have simply copied suggested code but this isn't gelling well with our existing code!

Any ideas how to alter the above to make it completely email client independant?

Comment: I added a simple example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76870414/1915920

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok turns out Spring has a helper class to hide all this mess away from you.

I've refactored all of the above code into the following and it works great;

```
            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
            message.setTo(mail.getTo());
            message.setFrom(mail.getFrom());
            message.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
            message.setText(mail.getText(), mail.getHtml());

            if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(mail.getPdfAttachmentFileName())) {
                File file = new File(uploadDir + "/" + mail.getPdfAttachmentFileName());
                DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(new FileInputStream(file), "application/pdf");
                message.addAttachment(mail.getPdfAttachmentFileName(), dataSource);
            }
```

Comment: Ya, the original structure of your message was all messed up.  What you needed was a new outer multipart/mixed part that contained two parts - the original multipart/alternative part, and the new pdf attachment part.